# How to get pytest-cov only if total coverage lower then 90%

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage, test-coverage, pytest-cov

So as I understood, pytest-cov has an option to fail if total coverage is lower than some %. But can I output hole tablet only in case if total cov is lower then 90% and if it is upper it won't show anything?

Example of command line code

Comment: Your post is missing the example.

Answer (score 0):

pytest-cov doesn't have this option, but you don't have to use pytest-cov to produce the report. Use the plugin to run coverage, then in a separate command, produce the report: `coverage report`.  You can conditionally run that separate command based on whatever condition you want.